# How to get the class object of a Java generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have following class:

```
public abstract class AbstractService<PersistenceClass extends IPersistence,
    RequestClass, ResponseClass> {

    public String processRequest(final String aRequestAsText)
    {
        [...]

        final RequestClass request = mapper.readValue(aRequestAsText, 
            RequestClass);

        [...]
    }

}
```

The *mapper.readValue* invokation is normally implemented as

```
mapper.readValue(aRequestAsText, Request.class)
```

How can I code it, if the class **RequestClass** is a generic?

**Update 1 (06.09.2013):** This code seems to work:

```
public class GenericTypeBindigsFinder implements IGenericTypeBindigsFinder {

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    @Override
    public List<Class> getGenericTypes(final Class aClass) {
        final List<Class> result = new LinkedList<Class>();

        final ParameterizedType gen = (ParameterizedType) aClass.getGenericSuperclass();

        final Type [] types = gen.getActualTypeArguments();

        for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            if (types[i] instanceof Class)
            {
                final Class clazz = (Class)types[i];
                result.add(clazz);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

You can find the corresponding unit test [here](https://github.com/dpisarenko/altruix-android-prototyping-tools/blob/master/android-prototyping-tools-server/src/test/java/ru/altruix/androidprototyping/server/services/GenericTypeBindigsFinderTest.java).

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the type parameter from a generic declaration?

Comment: No, I want to get the class object of `RequestClass` (sort of `RequestClass.class`).

Comment: @DmitriPisarenko : Please don't use backticks for non-code, see e.g. [here why](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/7437/88)

Comment: `request.getClass()` should do the trick for you, as @ragatskynet answered below.

Comment: @Mauren See my comment to ragatskynet's answer.

Comment: @Panther `mapper.readValue` is code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to access the generic types bound in AbstractService. You can do it via reflection. See the example code here:

```
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.lang.reflect.TypeVariable;

public class GenericClass extends GenericSuper<String, Integer> {
  public GenericClass() {
    ParameterizedType gen = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    TypeVariable<?> typeVars[] = getClass().getSuperclass().getTypeParameters();
    Type [] types = gen.getActualTypeArguments();
    for (int i = 0; i < typeVars.length; i++) {
      System.out.println("Generic parameter " + typeVars[i] + 
                         " is bound to " + types[i]);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GenericClass();
  }
}

class GenericSuper<X, Y> {};
```

Output is:

```
Generic parameter X is bound to class java.lang.String
Generic parameter Y is bound to class java.lang.Integer
```

You can cast `types[i]` to Class.

For a much more sophisticated solution, see [getTypeArguments(...)](https://code.google.com/p/cleartk/source/browse/cleartk-util/src/main/java/org/cleartk/util/ReflectionUtil.java).

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass `object` or an `interface` preferably to the method, then you can get the class of it with the `getClass()` method or maybe `instanceof`.

Comment: I need the class of *RequestClass* in order to create an instance of it. So I can't use your solution. Basically, this is JSON parsing - *mapper* takes a text and generates a request object, which represents that text. In order to do so, it needs the class of the request.

Comment: This case you should try using the Factory pattern for the creation of the class you need. Bare polymorphism is enough, no need of generics. There is a small article on this here (but you can find many other resources of course): http://java.dzone.com/articles/factory-design-pattern